# Angular PrimeNG using purchased template

Tags: angular, primeng

Im actually quite new to codeing in general and supposed to work with the PrimeNg Paradise Template. I managed to get the free version of PrimeNg running, but Ive no clue how to include the paradise template. My boss just sent me the zip-folder but also doesnt know how to use it.. I would be super happy about some advice here! the only tutorial I found was about including the apollo template, but apperently the folder structure is different so it didnt help..
In the documentation it also says ".. extract the contents of the Paradise zip file distribution .." which of course I did, but I am not quite sure how to go on. I am sure that it has to be possible to somehow get the template inside a new, empty projekt so that I`m able to start developing with all the functionaltities of the template, but how exactly does the extracted folder come into play?

Comment: Have you seen: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/setup ?

Comment: In angular.json file you should have a property "styles" pointing to a free theme if you followed the PrimeNg documentation. Just change the reference from the free theme to your local theme in the assets folder

Comment: Yes, I`ve seen and followed this.

Comment: I`m not quite sure if I yet fully understand the template and themes - is the Pradise template just a set of themes, while the functionality comes from the components like buttons and stuff that is open source, so when I add the theme as you said I already included everything of the premium version? If so, then what is all the stuff in the app folder of the paradise template?

Comment: You have a free framework called PrimeNg that have many UI components. The styles applied to those components are called themes. When you import correctly the premium theme ( i don't know if further authentication is needed ) the styles are applied to your angular app with the Primeng components. Without more information I can't tell you anything else...

Comment: Okay, so this is the template I`m talking about: https://www.primefaces.org/layouts/paradise-ng as it is not just a premium theme, but a complete template, I would think it contains way more then just the themes. In that case, I somehow have to include the functionalities that are different/addidtional to the free framework. Appreciate your help!

Comment: There's a detailed explanation for using the theme [here](https://www.primefaces.org/paradise-ng/#/documentation). In any case, I'm pretty sure that if you purchase a theme you get some kind of premium support for it. I'd try contacting their support.